# Использовать фрагменты или активити?

Tags: android-fragment, activity

В моем приложении должно быть около 100 экранов.
Структура такова, что на первом активити 10 cardview. Каждая card ведет в свое активити.
И там в каждой activity еще по 5- 6 карточек, которые в свою очередь показывают информацию на новых actvty. Все.

Информация 99% текст вью. Динамического ничего нету. Только стандартные расписания графики итд.
У меня вся информация хранится в string.
Через интент по клику на cardview я перехожу на новую активность и через backpressed ее завершаю. Каждая активити имеет свое оформлерие и свой текст вью или несколько штук.
Основной "косяк" в том, что активити слишком много. Около 50 на данный момент. Все советуют применять фрагменты. Хотя фрагменты нужны для гибкости но гибкость тут особо не нужна.
И уверенно как правильно мне толком никто не ответил. В оф источниках применять такое количество активити никто не запрещает и зла никакого в этом не вижу.приложение летает и на старых телефонах и на новых. Ориентация только вертикальная.
правильный ли такой подход или переходить на фрагменты?